# Initiating blur/focus on some property change

Tags: ember.js

I've got an `Ember.TextField` in my view. I would like the field to focus when a certain property in the app changes. I have learned how to bind callbacks to the focus event but is there any way to initiate the focus of a field based on a binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fiddle that I think does what you're asking.

http://jsfiddle.net/algesten/MGfAd/1/

Code for completeness:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.model = Ember.Object.create({
    someProp: 123,
});

App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({

    value: 'foo',

    autoFocus: function () {
        if (App.model.someProp === "42") {
            this.$().focus();
        }
    }.observes('App.model.someProp')

});
​
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view App.MyTextField}}
</script>

<br/>Try changing this field to '42' and see that the focus moves.

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.model.someProp"}}
</script>
​
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Ember approaches binding in several different ways and I sometimes find that I completely forget about observers as an option.